# Why does data node shut down when I run hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, ioexception

I have hadoop 1.0.4 installed on ubuntu 11.0.4 in VirtualBox(same as my hostname), somehow the data node shuts down giving the following error in the log files

```
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-08-18 19:52:21,301 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-08-18 19:52:21,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-08-18 19:52:21,412 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-08-18 19:52:21,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-08-18 19:52:23,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-08-18 19:52:23,276 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-08-18 19:52:26,887 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 457871323; datanode namespaceID = 2066655210
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1665)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1682)

2013-08-18 19:52:26,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Any idea why?How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had this happen a few times. If restarting the data node doesn't help, then do the following:

1. Restart Hadoop
2. Go to /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current
3. Open VERSION (i.e. by `vim VERSION`)
4. Record namespaceID
5. Go to /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/current
6. Open VERSION (i.e. by `vim VERSION`)
7. Replace the namespaceID with the namespaceID you recorded in step 4.

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for step by step guidance !

Answer (score 1):

This usually results when you format the namenode and don't do a datanode clean up and you namespace changes.

**Probable solution:**

Try deleting the **/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data** directory and restart the datanode

Comment: I solved it just after posting it here by reading Micheal Gnoll's tutorial.Thanks anyways

Comment: Can you help me with this one ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307328/hquorumpeer-and-hregionserver-processes-not-running-in-pseudodistributed-hbase-w

Comment: Can you please help me with this? stackoverflow.com/questions/19021982/hadoop-multi-node-cluster-installation-on-ubuntu-issue-troubleshoot. I'm getting similar error messages and I think its a firewall issue, but I can't be sure. Please take a look. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is well known problem when we format the name node. Please refer below url:

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#javaioioexception-incompatible-namespaceids

Comment: Actually I solved it just after posting by going over there.Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I lost my data on namenode.
I had to format my namenode with

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

After starting namenode, datanode was failing to start because of VERSION problem

Then I need to remove all the data from datanodes also.

I can simply clean data folder in dfs (/{hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data/*) and restart datanode

i.e `rm -rf /{hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data/*`

OR

delete the VERSION file (/{hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data/current/VERSION) and 
restart datanode

Answer (score -2):

```
Restart Hadoop
Go to /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current
Open VERSION (i.e. by vim VERSION)
Record namespaceID
Go to /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/current
Open VERSION (i.e. by vim VERSION)
Replace the namespaceID with thve namespaceID you recorded in step 4.
```

to do this above steps,
i dont have any files in the data folder /tmp/data