# HQuorumPeer and HRegionServer processes not running and hbase shuts down in pseudodistributed hbase why?

Tags: process, hbase

I am running `hbase-0.94.01` with `hadoop-1.04` by following a tutorial according to which I should get the following when I run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps`

```
$JPS
5417 TaskTracker
5083 NameNode
5761 HRegionServer
5658 HMaster
6015 Jps
5613 HQuorumPeer
5171 DataNode
5327 JobTracker
5262 SecondaryNameNode
```

but I get the following processes only why?

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps
6027 TaskTracker
5369 NameNode
6329 HMaster
6438 Jps
5560 DataNode
5836 JobTracker
5753 SecondaryNameNode
```

Printscreen of Hbase master UI

[image: http://localhost:60010/master-status]

Printscreen of Zookeeper Dump

[image]

The HMaster also shuts down after some time and the UI's don't show up on refresh
Here is the `hbase-site.xml` contents

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

Hmaster logs:

```
2013-08-19 01:05:49,634 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKAssign: master:57303-0x14093078e510001 Creating (or updating) unassigned node for 70236052 with OFFLINE state
2013-08-19 01:05:49,676 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Handling transition=M_ZK_REGION_OFFLINE, server=VirtualBox,57303,1376856285325, region=70236052/-ROOT-
2013-08-19 01:05:49,682 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:49,683 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Using pre-existing plan for region -ROOT-,,0.70236052; plan=hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:49,683 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Assigning region -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:49,683 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: New connection to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:51,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up.
2013-08-19 01:05:51,706 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168, trying to assign elsewhere instead; retry=7
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 after attempts=1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.handleConnectionException(HBaseRPC.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.getServerConnection(ServerManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assignRoot(AssignmentManager.java:2342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.assignRoot(HMaster.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupConnection(HBaseClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:208)
    ... 15 more
2013-08-19 01:05:51,712 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:51,712 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: No previous transition plan was found (or we are ignoring an existing plan) for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 so generated a random one; hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168; 1 (online=1, available=1) available servers
2013-08-19 01:05:51,712 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKAssign: master:57303-0x14093078e510001 Creating (or updating) unassigned node for 70236052 with OFFLINE state
2013-08-19 01:05:51,794 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Handling transition=M_ZK_REGION_OFFLINE, server=VirtualBox,57303,1376856285325, region=70236052/-ROOT-
2013-08-19 01:05:51,800 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:51,801 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Using pre-existing plan for region -ROOT-,,0.70236052; plan=hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:51,801 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Assigning region -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:51,801 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: New connection to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:53,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up.
2013-08-19 01:05:53,813 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168, trying to assign elsewhere instead; retry=8
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 after attempts=1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.handleConnectionException(HBaseRPC.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.getServerConnection(ServerManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assignRoot(AssignmentManager.java:2342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.assignRoot(HMaster.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupConnection(HBaseClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:208)
    ... 15 more
2013-08-19 01:05:53,820 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:53,820 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: No previous transition plan was found (or we are ignoring an existing plan) for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 so generated a random one; hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168; 1 (online=1, available=1) available servers
2013-08-19 01:05:53,820 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKAssign: master:57303-0x14093078e510001 Creating (or updating) unassigned node for 70236052 with OFFLINE state
2013-08-19 01:05:53,968 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Handling transition=M_ZK_REGION_OFFLINE, server=VirtualBox,57303,1376856285325, region=70236052/-ROOT-
2013-08-19 01:05:53,977 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:53,977 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Using pre-existing plan for region -ROOT-,,0.70236052; plan=hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:53,977 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Assigning region -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:53,978 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: New connection to localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:56,032 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up.
2013-08-19 01:05:56,034 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to localhost,44471,1376856320168, trying to assign elsewhere instead; retry=9
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to localhost/127.0.0.1:44471 after attempts=1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.handleConnectionException(HBaseRPC.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.getServerConnection(ServerManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assignRoot(AssignmentManager.java:2342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.assignRoot(HMaster.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupConnection(HBaseClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:208)
    ... 15 more
2013-08-19 01:05:56,058 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Found an existing plan for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 destination server is localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:05:56,058 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: No previous transition plan was found (or we are ignoring an existing plan) for -ROOT-,,0.70236052 so generated a random one; hri=-ROOT-,,0.70236052, src=, dest=localhost,44471,1376856320168; 1 (online=1, available=1) available servers
2013-08-19 01:08:45,954 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.lang.RuntimeException: Master not initialized after 200 seconds
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2100)
2013-08-19 01:08:45,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true; fsShutdownHook=Thread[Thread-27,5,main]
2013-08-19 01:08:45,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Shutdown hook
2013-08-19 01:08:45,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping server on 44471
2013-08-19 01:08:45,975 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 1 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,976 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 2 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 3 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 4 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,978 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 5 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 7 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 8 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 9 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 0 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,981 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 1 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 2 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 3 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 4 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 5 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 6 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,985 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 7 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 8 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: REPL IPC Server handler 0 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: REPL IPC Server handler 1 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: REPL IPC Server handler 2 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping IPC Server listener on 44471
2013-08-19 01:08:46,004 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:45,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: PRI IPC Server handler 9 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 6 on 44471: exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2013-08-19 01:08:46,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2013-08-19 01:08:46,046 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.SplitLogWorker: Sending interrupt to stop the worker thread
2013-08-19 01:08:46,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Stopping infoServer
2013-08-19 01:08:46,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.SplitLogWorker: SplitLogWorker interrupted while waiting for task, exiting: java.lang.InterruptedException
2013-08-19 01:08:46,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.SplitLogWorker: SplitLogWorker localhost,44471,1376856320168 exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,177 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60030
2013-08-19 01:08:46,198 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Block cache LRU eviction started; Attempting to free -75102.73 KB of total=473.27 KB
2013-08-19 01:08:46,203 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.snapshot.RegionServerSnapshotManager: Stopping RegionServerSnapshotManager gracefully.
2013-08-19 01:08:46,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer$CompactionChecker: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.compactionChecker exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LogRoller: LogRoller exiting.
2013-08-19 01:08:46,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.cacheFlusher exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:08:46,210 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker: Stopping catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@125257b
2013-08-19 01:08:46,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server localhost,44471,1376856320168; all regions closed.
2013-08-19 01:08:46,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.logSyncer exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:46,228 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: closing hlog writer in hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase/.logs/localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:08:46,634 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLog: Moved 1 log files to /hbase/.oldlogs
2013-08-19 01:08:46,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168 closing leases
2013-08-19 01:08:46,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168 closed leases
2013-08-19 01:08:53,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer$PeriodicMemstoreFlusher: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.periodicFlusher exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:53,295 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Split Thread to finish...
2013-08-19 01:08:53,295 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Large Compaction Thread to finish...
2013-08-19 01:08:53,295 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Waiting for Small Compaction Thread to finish...
2013-08-19 01:08:53,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.leaseChecker closing leases
2013-08-19 01:08:53,311 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168.leaseChecker closed leases
2013-08-19 01:08:53,378 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RegionServerTracker: RegionServer ephemeral node deleted, processing expiration [localhost,44471,1376856320168]
2013-08-19 01:08:53,388 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: based on ZK, current region=-ROOT-,,0.70236052 is on server=VirtualBox,57303,1376856285325 server being checked=: localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:08:53,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Master doesn't enable ServerShutdownHandler during initialization, delay expiring server localhost,44471,1376856320168
2013-08-19 01:08:53,402 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14093078e510002
2013-08-19 01:08:53,417 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14093078e510002 closed
2013-08-19 01:08:53,418 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: stopping server localhost,44471,1376856320168; zookeeper connection closed.
2013-08-19 01:08:53,418 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer:0;VirtualBox,44471,1376856320168 exiting
2013-08-19 01:08:53,419 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2013-08-19 01:08:53,420 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Starting fs shutdown hook thread.
2013-08-19 01:08:53,435 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x14093078e510002, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-08-19 01:08:53,437 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:52879 which had sessionid 0x14093078e510002
2013-08-19 01:08:53,452 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook finished.
Mon Aug 19 02:17:32 PKT 2013 Stopping hbase (via master)
```

HRegionServer logs:

```
Sun Aug 18 12:06:08 PKT 2013 Starting regionserver on VirtualBox
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
2013-08-18 12:06:11,747 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.94.10
2013-08-18 12:06:11,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo: Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/tags/0.94.10RC0 -r 1504995
2013-08-18 12:06:11,748 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jenkins on Fri Jul 19 20:24:16 UTC 2013
2013-08-18 12:06:11,989 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf file: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10/conf/hbase-site.xml; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 3; The element type "property" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
```

There are no other logs except for these two.

Comment: Did you see the logs for those specific daemons? They should say something. If possible edit your question put stack traces of the errors that you see in the logs, if any.

Comment: I looked into the logs, It reports a fatal error in HRegionServers that happened yesterday.Can this be the reason?

Comment: Those are not logs. Please post the stack traces showing in the log file.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the question while you commented so I couldn't see you asked for logs ... i had a look at them my self after editing the question and watching your comment...updated them

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the HRegionServer log, the following line says -

```
2013-08-18 12:06:11,989 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: error parsing conf 
file: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10
/conf/hbase-site.xml; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 3; The element type "property" must be
terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
```

your /home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10/conf/hbase-site.xml has a non-matching  tag. Make sure your hbase-site.xml is valid with proper syntax.

```
<property>

</property>
```

Comment: That error occurred yesterday and I corrected it then.But this problem occurred today.I think I should consider re-installing hbase