# Where are the logs for HRegionServer?

Tags: logging, hadoop, configuration, hbase

When running jps, I see that I have no HRegionServer running, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307328/hquorumpeer-and-hregionserver-processes-not-running-and-hbase-shuts-down-in-pseu) question.

But in that question, he's showing some HRegionServer logs that I can't find. All I have about HRegionServer is part of the general hbase log:

```
2014-06-16 16:42:58,845 FATAL [RS:0;test-254:35769] regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server test-254.office,35769,1402929575620: Initi
alization of RS failed.  Hence aborting RS.
java.io.IOException: Received the shutdown message while waiting.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.blockAndCheckIfStopped(HRegionServer.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:785)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-06-16 16:42:58,848 FATAL [RS:0;test-254:35769] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2014-06-16 16:42:58,848 INFO  [RS:0;test-254:35769] regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Initialization of RS failed.  Hence aborting RS.
```

I have nothing HMaster/HRegionServer specific as the guy in that question. Do I need to specify it in some property?

Answer (score 1):

Region server logs can be located at the following location.

```
  RegionServer: $HBASE_HOME/logs/hbase-<user>-regionserver-<hostname>.log
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not there, only the master logs are there.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudera 6.3.1 it's in /var/log/hbase/hbase-cmf-hbase-REGIONSERVER-host.log.out